# How to specify static method as annotation value in Java

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I want to provide an annotation as the following:

```
public @interface CloneField
{
    String sourceField();
    Class<?> customCloner();
}
```

Where people can annotation fields on their classes and some framework will automatically copy fields to their classes instances by running a method from the customCloner on an external data source object.
For example:

```
class Test {
    @CloneField(sourceField = "demoTest", customCloner = StringToIntCloner.class)
    private int testField;
```

This will copy a string value from a field named demoTest on the external data source object into an int field on the user's object.
Since the customCloner doesn't hold any data I would want to define the cloning method as static without the need to instantiate it just for calling a method.
Usually I would define the custom cloner class as:

```
Class <? extends FieldCloner> customCloner;
```

where FieldCloner has a method for cloning.
But since static methods are not supported on interfaces there isn't a clean way to do so.
Is there an elegant way to do so in Java 7?
Beside the problem of running the method which can be solved by reflection I want to verify at compile time that the customCloner class has the appropriate method for cloning.

Comment: uum... public static void cloneField in customCloner?

Comment: But how can I access this method without reflection which is ugly and slow? Since there is no interface with static method there isn't a clean way to do so. @noone

Comment: You can't. Annotations are only useful with reflection.

Comment: What is the `sourceField` supposed to specify? On what class?

Comment: Added the required information to the question. @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: You'll also need to specify what _the external data source object_ is, either explicitly or through some convention.

Comment: The verifying (last sentence of question) can be done using a annotation-processor. You can specify the annotation processor as argument of javac (see options -proc, -processor, -processorpath at [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#options)) or use your IDE for that. However you likely have to use the package `javax.lang.model` instead of reflection, since the .class files are not available at compile-time.